# OpenGL compute shader extension

Tags: opengl, graphics, opengl-4, compute-shader

I have a problem with creating compute shader.

My program seems to not know `GLenum type GL_COMPUTE_SHADER` when I'm trying to create shader with `glCreateShader() func`.

My graphics card is kinda low-end but when I check for `GL_ARB_compute_shader` extension it is present so that shouldn't be a problem I guess.

Is there something that I have to do to enable this extension or is there another problem and I have to use OpenCL?

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL Compute Shaders are new in version 4.3. I'm guess you have headers that predate that version. However, even if you got newer headers, your GPU or driver may be too old to support OpenGL 4.3. What version does your hardware return for glGetString(GL_VERSION)?

Comment: glGetString(GL_VERSION) returns 4.3.12618 Compatibility Profile Context 13.250.18.0 therefore I expect that it will support compute shaders. But my GPU is AMD mobility radeon 6490m and official amd info says it supports only OpenGL 4.1 so I dont know what to think.

Comment: Your GPU might support them then. You need updated OpenGL headers and/or GLEW.